# Using $_GET when updating a Database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP so it might sound stupid.

I'm trying to update the database, this is my code so far.

```
$pulldown = CleanUserInput($_GET['q']);
$name = CleanUserInput($_POST['name']);

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE Suppliers SET SuppName = ('$name') 
WHERE SuppName = ('$pulldown')");
```

How do I use $_GET to set the column that it will update?

Comment: why are you using $_POST and $_GET at the same time?

Comment: I'm trying to POST to the database and use GET to set the column that it will post to

Comment: I'm assuming his URI looks like script.php?q=xyz and he's sending the form to that.

Comment: yeah I have ?q= attached to the end of the URI

Comment: @user990175 that's crazy, and you can't set with a $_GET value you should use the php variables

Comment: Do you understand the difference between GET and POST? That is probably the most important point here.

Comment: there's no problem with that. Thechnically you can do it, it works. It's not very RESTful though

Comment: I feel sorry for Col. Shrapnel, I know he would have loved this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your variables are being passed correctly to this script, the 3rd line of your script should look like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE Suppliers SET SuppName = '".$name."' WHERE SuppName = '".$pulldown."';") or die(mysql_error());
```

To set the column name that is to be update via a $_GET variable, your code could look like this:

```
$pulldown = CleanUserInput($_GET['q']);
$name = CleanUserInput($_POST['name']);
$column_name = CleanUserInput($_GET['column_name']);
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE Suppliers SET `".$column_name."` = '".$name."' WHERE `".$column_name."` = '".$pulldown."';") or die(mysql_error());
```

Of course this will the replace the value in the column for the variable `$column_name`.  Not sure if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why would this make a difference?

Comment: @Asaph For one, strings in mySQL need to be surrounded by single or double quotes.

Comment: I think you should surround strings by either double or single quotes, depending on the content of the string.

Comment: @TusharDhoot: The OP's code _does_ have single quotes already.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind: That may be a good practice generally but it won't solve the OP's problem.

Comment: but how does this answer the question. His question was not how to fix the query, but how to improve it in order to "use $_GET to set the column that it will update" this sets SuppName, and not the column passed in GET

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind: PHP allows inlining variables in double quoted strings. Try it.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that, I haven't seen that syntax before.  I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your form has `<form method="post">`, and one of your `<input>` (or `<select>`) elements has a `name="q'` attribute, you'll find that in `$_POST`, not `$_GET`. While it's technically possible to mix `GET` and `POST` forms by appending a querystring to the url in your form's `action` attribute, I doubt thats what you're trying to do here.

As a sidenote, Your code looks vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A1). You should be using parameterized queries instead.

Answer (score 0):

short answer:

```
$column = CleanUserInput($_POST['column']);
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE Suppliers SET $column = '$name' WHERE SuppName = '$pulldown'");
```

but you should make sure you don't have sql injection problems. Make sure CleanUserInput saves you from that!

Comment: why -3???? I gave the correct answer, nobody else understood the question, that the column name should be passed. Even jeffery_the_wind copied my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE Suppliers SET SuppName = '{$name}' 
WHERE SuppName = '{$pulldown}'");
```

use this query..you have syntax error in your code